# How to affect one selected Row to a local variable in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I try to select one row from a table, and affect its value to a local declared variable I used the method below, but I got error.

**Method:**

```
DECLARE @A AS INT ;

SET @A=1;

WHILE @A<=10
BEGIN

DECLARE @R AS TABLE
SET @R = (SELECT * FROM Client c WHERE c.ID=@A)

SET @A=@A+1

END
```

**Error I got :**

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.
```

So please how can I affect the subquery result to the **R** local variable ?

Comment: You haven't completed the definition not `@R`. Tables have columns which also have data types. You also don't `SET` against a `TABLE` you `INSERT` into it; along with other DML operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table Variables cannot be assigned; you use DML to add data to a table variable.  From docs

> Assignment operation between table variables isn't supported.

[table (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

So something like:

```
DECLARE @R AS TABLE(ClientID int, Name nvarchar(200), ...)

INSERT INTO @R(ClientId, Name, ...) 
SELECT ClientId, Name, ...
FROM Client c 
WHERE c.ID=@A
```